# URL query string not changing with .htaccess file

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I have this url: http://example.org/product.php?course_id=$x

And I want this url changes to this: http://example.org/Course-Name

this is my code in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^  404page.php
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/$ /product.php?course_id=$1 [L,R]
```

Which is not working kindly tell me whats wrong with my code?

Comment: You would need a matching redirect, not just a rewrite. Currently you're letting the server understand the user-friendly URL but not redirecting to that user-friendly one from the real URL. NB the links in your HTML should be the ones you want to see, not the real ones that would then be redirected.

Comment: Is your .htaccess processed? Check in apache config if your directory has AllowOverride all

Comment: ok i change rewrite to redirect but still not working

Comment: yes its AllowOverride all

Comment: popnoodles kindly tell me how to redirect? i dont know exact syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove leading slash from your rule. Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+product\.php\?course_id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /product.php?course_id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Which URL isn't working and what is location of this .htaccess and your product.php files?

Comment: Did you delete your comment?

Comment: ops accidently i did, but thanku so much for your time it works now :))